# Trigger.io forge.facebook.ui not returning data

Tags: facebook, trigger.io

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [forge.facebook.ui callback never run](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13516726/forge-facebook-ui-callback-never-run)

I'm trying to use Trigger.io's facebook methods to display a friend selector. It displays properly but never returns any data.

`response` is always `null` even when a friend is selected. [According to the Facebook docs](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/dialogs/requests/) it should return `request` and `to` fields so I can capture to whom the request was sent.

Here is some sample code:

```
forge.facebook.ui({
    method: 'apprequests',
    title: 'Create Game',
    message: 'I challenge you to a game!'
}, function(response) {
    console.log('success response');
    console.log(''+response); // As string because logging null errors Catalyst
});
```

For this, Catalyst outputs

```
success response
null
```

And the Trigger Toolkit outputs

```
[DEBUG] Native call: {
[DEBUG]     callid = "F8446A0D-44AE-46E4-A587-16BEC78EE695";
[DEBUG]     method = "facebook.ui";
[DEBUG]     params =     {
[DEBUG]         message = "I challenge you to a game!";
[DEBUG]         method = apprequests;
[DEBUG]         title = "Create Game";
[DEBUG]     };
[DEBUG]     start = "1354655948.023";
[DEBUG] }
[DEBUG] Returning to javascript: {
[DEBUG]     callid = "F8446A0D-44AE-46E4-A587-16BEC78EE695";
[DEBUG]     content = "<null>";
[DEBUG]     status = success;
[DEBUG] }
```

Am I doing it wrong? Or is this library not working correctly?

**Update, 12/5/12**

It appears that this is an iOS only issue. It's happening on the iOS simulator (and device) for both iOS5 and iOS6. But works fine on the Android simulator:

```
[DEBUG] Native call "facebook.ui" with task.params: {"method":"apprequests","title":"Create Game","message":"I challenge you to a game!"}
[DEBUG] Returning: {"content":{"to[0]":"1175220065","request":"349563028475745"},"status":"success","callid":"548FE13D-69D9-415B-9A94-762D9F7C64B1"}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A fix for this will be included in v1.4.23 Trigger.io platform version.

Your success callback will be invoked with (for apprequests for example):

```
{"request":"519074534448448","to[0]":"105000524002524"}
```

**Note:** your success callback will still be invoked if the user hits cancel: `{}` will be passed as the callback parameter.

If they hit the `x` in the top-left corner, your failure callback will be invoked.

Comment: How long before 1.4.23 is released?